# Backbone.Deferred.Model: Why the unittest is not run?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, phantomjs, mocha.js, chai

Here is the code in question.

```
define (require) ->

  Backbone = require 'backbone'

  require 'backbone-deferred'

  class Data extends Backbone.Deferred.Model

    urlRoot: 'data'

    parse: (resp) ->
      resp.record or resp

    isValid: ->
      @get 'valid'

    # Newly introduced
    dataUrl: ->
      @get('data_url')?.replace /abc/, ''
```

And here is the unit test

```
define (require) ->

  Data         = require 'model/Data'

  describe 'dataurl', ->

    describe 'No change', ->
      data = new Data id: '123', name: 'Dummy', data_url: 'https://m/a.png'
      expect(data.dataUrl()).to.equal('https://m/a.png')
```

For some reason the test is not run by mocha.

I am using this html to drive the test

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mocha Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/mocha/mocha.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Tests for {%= name %}" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>
  <script src="../bower_components/mocha/mocha.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/chai/chai.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script src="../bower_components/requirejs/require.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <!-- Requirejs configuration -->
  <script src="../temp/local/scripts/config.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // Dumping console messages to /dev/null to avoid parsing error
    // when grunt:mocha_phantomjs is run
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('PhantomJS') >= 0) {
      var log = console.log
      console.log = function(message) {
        if (message.indexOf('<') === 0) {
          log.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))
        }
      }
    }

    // Mixpanel is not loaded for unit testing.
    // Redirecting mixpanel to /dev/null.
    window.mixpanel = {
      track: function() {}
    };

    require.config({
      baseUrl: "../temp/local/scripts",
      shim: {
        'chai-jquery': {
          deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'sinon': {
          exports: 'sinon'
        }
      },
      paths: {
        // Aliasing path to find the specs
        'specs': '../../specs',

        'sinon'      : '../../../bower_components/sinon/lib/sinon',
        'sinon-chai' : '../../../bower_components/sinon-chai/lib/sinon-chai',
        'chai-jquery': '../../../bower_components/chai-jquery/chai-jquery',
        'handlebars' : '../../../bower_components/handlebars/handlebars',

      }
    });

    runTests = function() {

      // Ensuring that jquery and chai-jquery are loaded
      require(
          ['jquery', 'chai-jquery', 'sinon-chai', 'handlebars'],
          function($, jqueryChai, sinonChai, Handlebars) {
        // Registering testing style in globals for easy access
        window.expect = chai.expect;
        chai.use(jqueryChai);
        chai.use(sinonChai)

        mocha.setup({
          ui: 'bdd',
          ignoreLeaks: true
        });

        // Protect from barfs
        console = window.console || function() {};

        // Don't track
        window.notrack = true;

        // Helper... not really needed but in case we want to do something fancy
        var runMocha = function() {
          mocha.run();
        };

        require([
          // Many other tests; removed for clarity
          'specs/data.spec'
        ], function() {
          // For xUnit and code coverage reports, we run the tests
          // using mocha-phantomjs runner.
          if (window.mochaPhantomJS) {
            mochaPhantomJS.run();
          }
          else {
            mocha.run();
          }
        });
      });

    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the output of the grunt test task

```
Running "mocha:default" (mocha) task
Testing: test/index.html


  ․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․
  ․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․
  ․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․
  ․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․
  ․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․
  ․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․
  ․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․
  ․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․
  ․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․
  ․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․․
  ․․․․․․․․․․․

  1081 passing (9s)

>> 1081 passed! (9.17s)
```

My questions are:

1) Number of test is changed at all after adding the new test. What are the possible reasons the new test is not picked up?

2) If I intentionally introduce an error in my unit test it will cause this in case of a test failure:

```
Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call. Use --force to continue.
```

I am sure it is related to the test but there is not enough information to diagnose the problem. How can I turn on logging or obtain additional information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test case should be defined using the `it` function instead of `describe` (which is used to group tests)

```
define (require) ->    
  Data = require 'model/Data'    
  describe 'dataurl', ->    
    it 'No change', ->
      data = new Data id: '123', name: 'Dummy', data_url: 'https://m/a.png'
      expect(data.dataUrl()).to.equal('https://m/a.png')
```

I have created [this jdfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vL1qn9r/) so you can see the difference with your original definition.

If you introduce an error in the test, if the test is not defined inside the `it` function then it will affect the whole test run. You can check it in this [other fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g23r9a6m/) (You will notice the second test doesn't run after the error in the wrong defined test)